# Mapbox-Android ¿Por qué motivo al comenzar la Navegación, el marcador navegación se mueve por su propia cuenta de un punto a otro?

Tags: android, mapbox

Para aquellas personas que trabajaron con Mapbox. Saben la razón de por qué este ícono de navegación se mueve por sí solo? yo necesito que dicho marcador se mueva con el cambio de ubicación de mi teléfono, o sea con el movimiento. Así como funciona en Google Maps. Les agradecería mucho saber su opinión o experiencia al respecto. Gracias!!!

```
private NavigationView navigationView;
private boolean dropoffDialogShown;
private Location lastKnownLocation;

private List<Point> puntos_clientes = new ArrayList<>();


private LocationComponent locationComponent;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    MapboxNavigation navigation = new MapboxNavigation(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.access_token_repartidor));

    setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_NoActionBar);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    //Punto de origen
    puntos_clientes.add(Point.fromLngLat(-60.446815, -26.784306));

    puntos_clientes.add(Point.fromLngLat(-60.448123,-26.784327));
    puntos_clientes.add(Point.fromLngLat(-60.448241,-26.790556));
    puntos_clientes.add(Point.fromLngLat(-60.448427,-26.792986));
    puntos_clientes.add(Point.fromLngLat(-60.446893,-26.792885));
    puntos_clientes.add(Point.fromLngLat(-60.444785,-26.794505));
    puntos_clientes.add(Point.fromLngLat(-60.442989,-26.792107));
    puntos_clientes.add(Point.fromLngLat(-60.442023,-26.793726));
    puntos_clientes.add(Point.fromLngLat(-60.442989,-26.792107));
    puntos_clientes.add(Point.fromLngLat(-60.438246,-26.794419));


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_repartidores);

    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
    navigationView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    navigationView.initialize(this);





}/************************** FIN DEL onCreate() **************************************/
```

Me doy cuenta que no tengo el código para saber la localización de mi GPS! tengo el mapa en otra activity con la ubicación actual de mi dispositivo (en un punto en el mapa) pero en el Navigation solo trazo una ruta desde diferentes puntos en el mapa. Será que en la documentación de Mapbox encuentre código para saber la localización de GPS Navigation?

Comment: Ejecutas en el simulador o en el dispositivo?

Comment: En el dispositivo crack!

Comment: Puedes agregar el código del método que captura la posición del GPS?

Comment: Ahí añadi algo de código

Comment: Bueno ese código agrega los puntos en el mapa, te faltaría como bien lo dices, el método para obtener las coordenadas del GPS

Comment: Buenísimo! dale! muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Bicho. Estuve viendo la documentación de Mapbox para tratar de obtener la ubicación de mi dispositivo. El problema es que no se bien cómo hacerlo. Porque en una Activity tengo el mapa cargado en un mapbview. Mientras que el mapa de navegación lo tengo en otra Activity. No se bien como hacerlo. Tenes idea donde puedo buscar?

Comment: Es necesario que estén separados? Puedes trabajar en un solo mapview

Comment: Lo ví más simple! porque en el mapa no necesito marcar una coordenada de destino con el onMapClick y por ende tampoco la ruta trazada para comenzar la navegación.  Sí necesito que de mi ubicación para comenzar en ese punto de origen donde estoy parado actualmente!